# Confused by the parameters of higher order functions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I write the following code, which calls the `fold` function.

```
fun operation(acc: Int, next: Int): Int {
    return acc * next
}
val items = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(items.fold(1, ::operation))
```

In the 5th line of the above code, the `fold` function uses the `operation` function.

This is reasonable because the `fold` function is declared to accept a function reference or lambda that takes exactly TWO parameters(3rd line of the following `fold` implementation from the Kotlin stdlib `_Collections.kt`)

```
public inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.fold(
        initial: R, 
        operation: (acc: R, T) -> R
): R {
    var accumulator = initial
    for (element in this) accumulator = operation(accumulator, element)
    return accumulator
}
```

What confuses me is that the `fold` function can also be fed with a one-parameter function `Int::times` like below.

```
val items = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(items.fold(1, Int::times))
```

AFAIK, `Int::times` is declared to be a one-parameter member function as below:

```
/** Multiplies this value by the other value. */
public operator fun times(other: Int): Int
```

I don't quite understand the contradiction. Does it have anything to do with the keyword `operator`?

Comment: The `times` function is a function on `Int`, so it actually has 2 parameters. The receiver `Int` that it's called on, and the `other` parameter.

Comment: @marstran Make an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public operator fun times(other: Int): Int
```

(or more specifically, `::times`) is actually of type `Int.(Int) -> Int`, which is the same as `(Int, Int) -> Int`. That allows for both `::times` and `::operator` to be used with `fold`.